is there a way to make zendesk webhooks always instant?
I've noticed that sometimes my zendesk webhooks from a trigger fire right away, within a second of the action that causes the trigger.
But sometimes they are slower, taking up to a minute to come in. Is there a way to make sure they always come in fast?

Often the delay is a result of the trigger processing time.  While much of the process flow is out of our control as users, what you may be able to do is review your triggers and make sure the logic is as simple as possible, and to put the webhook action into its own trigger and make sure that it is at the top of the list of triggers.  This should result in it being processed first and hopefully reducing the time to fire.
